# Fixing good Hive SQL query that throws parsing exception in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, parsing, hive, hiveql

Having the following query executed in Hive works fine:

```
ALTER TABLE schema.the_table 
DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION (PARTITION_DATE<'2020-03-22')
```

Partition date is type String, but that's OK. The goal is to drop partitions older than particular date.

On the other hand the same query but used in Spark(2.1):

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport.getOrCreate
spark.sql("""
ALTER TABLE schema.the_table 
DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION (PARTITION_DATE<'2020-03-22')
""")
```

Throws parsing exception

> User class threw exception:
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: mismatched input
> '<' expecting {')', ','}(line 1, pos 82)
>
> == SQL == ALTER TABLE schema.the_table DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION (PARTITION_DATE<'2020-03-22')

The question is where I can find the characters that must be escaped in Spark SQL and is there any way to write the same query in Spark SQL as in Hive?

Comment: This is a known bug in spark and it is currently being targeted to be fixed in version 3.1.0. Check the JIRA [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14922)

Comment: @ShreyJakhmola please, write the comment as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hive partitions cannot be dropped using spark.sql as of Spark version 3.0 due to a known bug and it is currently being targeted to be fixed in version 3.2.0. Check the JIRA [Spark-JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14922).